# How to Show random post on WP, except the last post

Tags: php, wordpress

I was able to locate part of the answer, I'm new to Wordpress.
Im looking to show random post on the main page, but except the last post
i found this

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');
function my_pre_get_posts($query) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set('orderby', 'rand');
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: By "last post" do you mean the last published post?

Comment: wordpress questions should be considered posted in 
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: yes, last published post, sorry :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code please use this code in functions.php file and enter the last post id which you need to exclude the post.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','my_pre_get_posts');
function my_pre_get_posts($query) {
if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
 $query->set('orderby', 'rand');
        $query->set('post__not_in',array(1));
}
}
```

Please use it and I 'm also searching a best possible solution in which you need not to enter the static last post id =1 .
Thanking you.